# Not able to install hstore in rails 4 on CENTOS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, centos

I am using rails 4 with database as postgres9.4.While using hstore type column for dynamic field .I am getting error

> PG::UndefinedFile: ERROR:  could not open extension control file
>   "/usr/pgsql-9.4/share/extension/hstore.control": No such file or
>   directory : CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS
>   "hstore"/var/www/Q3/mailchimp/campaign_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:592:in `async_exec'
>   /var/www/Q3/mailchimp/campaign_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:592:in`block in exec_no_cache'
>   /var/www/Q3/mailchimp/campaign_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:473:in `block in log'
>   /var/www/Q3/mailchimp/campaign_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in`
>   instrument'
>   /var/www/Q3/mailchimp/campaign_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:467:in `log'
>   /var/www/Q3/mailchimp/campaign_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:592:in`exec_no_cache'
>   /var/www/Q3/mailchimp/campaign_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:584:in `execute_and_clear'
>   /var/www/Q3/mailchimp/campaign_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:160:in`
>   exec_query'
>   /var/www/Q3/mailchimp/campaign_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:342:in `enable_extension'
>   /var/www/Q3/mailchimp/campaign_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:662:in`
>   block in method_missing'

I try

```
sudo yum install postgresql postgresql-contrib
sudo yum install postgresql-server.x86_64 postgresql94-contrib.x86_64
```

but don't work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Centos i by mistake install postgres8.3 packages but i was using postges9.4.
After removing postgres8.3 packages it works fine